# How to create an animation in python that will blow balls up around, and add bars between, random points

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to create an animation where balls blow up around a random set of points and bars are added between the points once a certain threshold is crossed, in particular I want to place a bar between two points only when half the distance between them is greater than or equal to the radius of the balls. I have two problems:

1. The original green points are behind the red balls, is there a way I can get those green points in front of the red balls?
2. The bars are adding between every point right away in the first step of the animation, is there something wrong with my if statement or do you see anything else that might be causing this problem?

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import numpy as np
import random
from math import sqrt

x_values = []
y_values = []

max_radius = 10     # max radius for the balls
num_of_steps = 50   # number of steps in the filtration
N = 15              # number of desired random points

radii = np.linspace(0, max_radius, num_of_steps) 

for i in range(N):
    x_values.append(random.randint(0,100))
    y_values.append(random.randint(0,100))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_values, y_values, color = 'green', marker = 'o', s = 15)

for r in radii:
    
    for i in range(len(x_values)):
        circle = Circle((x_values[i], y_values[i]), radius = r, fill = True, color = 'r', linewidth = 1)
        ax.add_patch(circle)

        if sqrt((x_values[i] - x_values[i-1])**2 + (y_values[i] - y_values[i-1])**2) / 2 >= r:
            ax.plot([x_values[i-1], x_values[i]], [y_values[i-1], y_values[i]], 'b-')
    
    plt.xlim(-5,105)
    plt.ylim(-5,105)
    plt.pause(0.0001)

plt.show()
```

And here is a picture of the output
[image]

Comment: So the distance `sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)` should be greater than half the radius when drawing a line?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I want to add a line whenever two balls intersect, so I believe I should place a line between two points whenever half of their distance is at least the length of the radius.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `<=` then? E.g. when the distance is _less_ than the radius, draw a line between them.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Ah wait! Yes, indeed I believe you are correct! It is most certainly the radius that is changing and not the distance, *face palm* . Thank you kindly!

Comment: Also on the dots: put those on the graph _after_ drawing the circles. Otherwise the circles draw over the points.